# Free Excel spreadsheet Component for SilverLight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I Need a Good Excel spreadsheet Component for Silver Light. I mean Free ones!!!

Comment: Perhaps you might describe your actual requirements?  In what way would the component need to be "Excel" as opposed to simple a spreadsheet component?

Comment: Thx
I use farpoint in my windows app , and i want same Component with those capabilities for my silver light app.
big problem is farpoint don't have any component for silver light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid is quiet good. Though you might end up writing a few lines of code here and there to implement a few extra features so that it matches the functionality of Excel (you know, things like filtering, sorting, automatic value recalculation, persistence, printing, etc.) but it is a Free one!!!

Comment: Thx
I know data grid can use for this problem. u need to make changes(template , code , style) and then test that.
so i have not enough time for this solution!!